# How do I update a track’s streamable property via the API?

Tags: php, api, boolean, soundcloud

Using the [SoundCloud PHP wrapper](https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud), I can successfully update a song’s title, privacy, genre, tags. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with regard to the streamable property. When I send a `true` value to `track[streamable]`, it remains false.

Here’s what I’m working with:

```
<?php
require_once 'Soundcloud.php';
require './globaldatabase.php';
$access_token = $_POST['access_token'];
$trackid = $_POST['trackid'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
$tag_list = $_POST['tag_list'];
$privacy = $_POST['privacy'];
$release = $_POST['release'];
$streamable = true;
if($privacy=='disabled'){
    $streamable = false;
    $privacy = 'private';
}

$client = new Services_Soundcloud($sc_clientid, $sc_clientsecret);
$client->setAccessToken($access_token);

try {
    $track = json_decode($client->get('tracks/'.$trackid));
    $client->put('tracks/' . $track->id, array(
        'track[title]' => $title,
        'track[genre]' => $genre,
        'track[tag_list]' => $tag_list,
        'track[sharing]' => $privacy,
        'track[release]' => $release,
        'track[streamable]' => $streamable
        ));
    $return = $client->get('tracks/' . $track->id);
    $return_array[] = json_decode($return);
    echo json_encode($return_array);

} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the track attribute `api_streamable` to `true`.